# High-dimensional polytopes

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, polygons

I have two questions regarding polytopes in high dimensions, $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d > 3$, that I could not find resources for on the web for. Suppose I have a polytope that is non-convex:

1. How can I tell if a point (in the same dimension $d$) is within the polytope, and also the distance to the closest "edge"/constraint? If it was convex and I could use the H-representation $\{x: Ax+b \geq 0\}$ to check if all constraints are positive. But since it is non-convex, what representation is suitable?
2. Another way to solve this is to do a convex decomposition of the complex shape to simpler and convex shapes, and then I could use the H-representation. I saw algorithms like HACD but I could not find convex decomposition for dimensions higher than $d=3$. Does something like this exist?

EDIT:
I left the representation of the non-convex polytope vague on purpose because I will conform myself to what is best suited here. I am starting from defining a physical object in $d=2$ or $3$, so I imagine that I have a bunch of vertices and edges, and from that I concatenate them (lets say 2 together) so they are in a higher dimension. The two concatenated objects are independent (if it helps). So for example, lets say I have an L-shape in the x-y plane, $\{(0,0), (1,0), (1,0.5), (0.5,0.5), (0.5, 1), (0,1), (0,0)\}$ and I concatenate two of these objects. How do I know, if the point $p=(0.1,0.8,0.0,-0.1)$ is in this polyhedron or not?
You could tell me to check each object by itself, but I might also add dimensions that are not coming from the physical space. So even one object could have $d>3$ dimensions to it.

Thank you.

Comment: Since your question is about algorithms for solving a certain problem, it might be useful to describe how you like to think of a "non-convex polytope"? I.e., how are you imagining the non-convex polytope being given to you?

Comment: Thanks @AndréHenriques, I edited the original post, I hope it didn't make it even more confusing

Comment: "I concatenate them (lets say 2 together) so they are in a higher dimension": Could you explain what it means to "concatenate" two planar polygons?

Comment: Assume that you have two points and each of them needs to be in its respective L-shaped polygon described by some (different) x-y axes. So a point in the high dimension is [xp1,yp1,xp2,yp2] and I need to check if it is in the "higher-dimension" world of the [x1,y1,x2,y2] axes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you could consider the facet hyperplanes.
Then you might check whether those run through the origin or not.
If none does you might decompose your polytope into the various facet-centri-pyramids.
If the facets themselves aren't convex you might iterate that same process again.
Thus you finally get left with convex polytopes only and you could do your original quest with those (in the known manner).

(Sure, that does not help for the most general cases with holes running through, but it well solves for the prominent class of starshaped polytopes.)

--- rk

Comment: Hi, I'd love for clarifications because I could not follow. Why do the facets going through the origin say if it is convex? At this point, I've resulted in doing Delaunay triangulation on the 2-D subspaces but I'm not really content because it is not even remotely optimal in any way.

Comment: It just depends on the overall placing. And then just happens to become a degeneracy as the according facet-centri-pyramid would have vanishing height.